# Porque as notificações push do meu app utilizando one signal não chegam com o app fechado ou em segundo plano?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, push-notification, api

Estou utilizando one signal para enviar as push notification para meu app, vi vários tutorias para criar as notificações e fiz assim :
configuração do

app/build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

configuração do android/buildgradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.12.10]'

    }
}
```

adicionei ele ao pubspeck.yml:

```
onesignal_flutter:2.6.1
```

este é o meu main:

````
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    OneSignal.shared.init(
      "id do one signal",
      iOSSettings: {
        OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
        OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: false,
      },
    );
    OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);

    OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState().then((status) {
      UserModel.of(context).playerId = status.subscriptionStatus.userId;
    });
    return ScopedModel<UserModel>(
      model: UserModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "ARPA3I",
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 125, 141)
        ),
        home: Splash(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: {
          'LoginScreen': (context) => LoginScreen(),
      },
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Preciso que sejam enviadas notificações para meu app todas as vez que a variavel que esta no firebase for igual a 1 (ela recebe 1 e 0, quando o sensor é acionado recebe 1 enquanto esta desligado fica no valor 0),para isso criei este if que pega o valor do sensor no firebase e cria esta notificação quando ele é igual a 1, mas só esta funcionando enquanto o app esta aberto quando ele esta fechado e em segundo plano não recebo notificações, este é o código:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
          stream: _btRef.onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var _bt = Botao_pan.fromJson(snapshot.data.snapshot.value['Variaveis']);
            print("Bt: ${_bt.botao_pan} ");
            if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError && _bt.botao_pan == 1) {
              btnnotify();
              return AnimatedContainer(
                  height: 160.0,
                  width: 160.0,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),....

btnnotify() async{
   await OneSignal.shared.postNotification(
     OSCreateNotification(
       playerIds: ['player id qualquer'],
       content: "O botão foi pressionado!",
       heading: "Alerta"
     ),
   );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

No seu código, o próprio aplicativo verifica se no Firebase está 0 ou 1 e emite a notificação, seria isso?

Se for, provavelmente o código não está sendo executado quando está fechado/segundo plano por isso não emite a notificação.

A minha sugestão é fazer essa verificação no back-end, assim quando for 1 ele envia a notificação para o app, dessa forma será exibido mesmo em segundo plano ou com o app fechado, basta fazer uma requisição, por exemplo:

```
{   "app_id": "Chave One Signal",   "subtitle": {"en": "Subtitulo"},   "headings": {"en": "Aplicativo 1"},   "include_player_ids": ["Player Id do Dispositivo"],   "contents": {"en": "Mensagem de notificação..."} }
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/using-postman

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification